# Animate CC HTML5 canvas basics.. nothing's working

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, animate-cc

I've converted an old Flash game to the HTML5 canvas in Animate CC.
I managed to make external links, and a gotoAndStop work on the intro screen.  Cool.

On the second frame I have a complex menu which lets you customize the character.  Nothing I do within this menu seems to work.  I've been reduced to trying:

```
this.hair1.visible = false;
```

...which I can get to work on the preloader screen, on another MC, but not within this menu.  What does this mean? (hair1 is on the main timeline within the same menu movieclip)

I get a lot of warnings, but that was the case from the very start, no matter which part of the code I was translating.  All stuff like "filters are not supported".

So I'm trying to figure out more.. I'm trying

```
console.log(this.hair1.currentFrame);
this.hair1.visible = false;
```

console.log is the equivalent of a trace statement right?  It doesn't trace anything in the Output window :/
Am I even using that feature right?
I'm having a really hard time finding resources to learn how to code in java within Animate.  Anybody got any resources?

Comment: If you want to learn, I wouldn't start by converting old FLA files. Many old FLA files are full of spaghetti code (at least, in my experience) which is very hard to convert to javascript. Perhaps you should start with an empty Animator CC file, and learn javascript basics by googling for some good beginner tutorials. For example: https://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript/

Comment: Thank you @Kokodoko  I'm thinking you're probably right.  My head is spinning with all the ways my old Flash stuff might be hindering the progress.  Thank you for the link.  I'm checking it out =)

Comment: I'm googling "spaghetti code" lol.  So in this case you're saying, longer and more complex than necessary, yeah?  Coo...

Comment: It sounds like you are starting to learn from the very beginning. I wouldn't start with old FLA files, because you will probably teach yourself a wrong approach. If you google for "javascript basics" you will find a lot of good tutorials, for example this one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics

Comment: To see things such as console.log(), and potentially debug your errors, you'll have to use the developer tools in Chrome/IE/Firefox/etc.  I prefer using Chrome's developer tools.  FYI, a single javascript error could be what is derailing your canvas.